# TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe' for interp_func(x, xp, fp, left, right)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the following function:

```
def interpolate_values(A):
    ''' fills values between pairs of events'''
    if type(A) ==list :
        A= np.array(A)
    ok = ~pd.isna(A)
    xp = ok.nonzero()[0]
    fp = A[~pd.isna(A)]
    x  = pd.isna(A).nonzero()[0]
    A[pd.isna(A)] = np.interp(x, xp, fp)
    A = [round(i) for i in A]
    return A
```

The following error is produced:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Pointing to the line:

```
A[pd.isna(A)] = np.interp(x, xp, fp)
```

A is passed from the following function:

```
def generate_appliance_powerseries(appliance_pairs,DelP):
    ''' generates full power series of appliances'''
    print ("3 of 6> generates full power series of appliances")
    appliance_signatures = OrderedDict()
    power_series = OrderedDict()
    ctlf = OrderedDict()
    for i in range(len(appliance_pairs)):
        events = appliance_pairs[i]
        timeseq= []
        powerseq  = []
        for event in events:
            start= event[0]
            end = event[1]
            duration = end - start
            instance = []
            instance.append([DelP[start]])
            temp= np.repeat(np.nan,duration-1).tolist()
            instance.append(temp)
            instance.append([abs(DelP[end])])
            final = [j for sub in instance for j in sub]
            timeval = range(start,end+1,1)
            #print (event)
            powerval = interpolate_values(final) if sum(pd.isna(final)) else final
            timeseq.append(timeval)
            powerseq.append(powerval)
        powerseq =  [j for sub in powerseq for j in sub]
        timeseq =  [j for sub in timeseq for j in sub]
        power_series[i] = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':timeseq,'power':powerseq})
        appliance_signatures[i] = pd.DataFrame(powerseq)

    return power_series, appliance_signatures
```

Could anybody know what is the issue?
Please let me know if any additional info is needed.

Comment: What is ```A``` when you pass it to ```interpolate_values```? It looks like it is a pandas series of object dtype, so you need to convert it to float64 before you do the interpolation.

Comment: Is that the full traceback?  Tell us about the arrays involved is this expression. We shouldn't have to deduce those details from the unkown `A`.

Comment: I have just edited the question.

Comment: Can't you describe `A`, eg shape and dtype? How you create it is less important than what it is.  But lets focus on what you pass to `interp`

Comment: You didn't write this code yourself, right?  Because if you, you would know  what each of the `interp` arguments  was - `x`, `xp`, `fp`.  Both what they were supposed to be, and what they actually were.  The error suggests at least one is the wrong dtype (and possibly shape as well).

Comment: When I have this issue, even when xp and fp are arrays of 'floats', I need to 'reassure' python with `xp = np.array(xp, dtype='float64)` and the same for `fp`. Pretty annoying, but works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Running your function on simple float array:

```
In [265]: import pandas as pd
In [266]: A = np.arange(10.)
In [267]: A[1::2]=np.nan
In [268]: A
Out[268]: array([ 0., nan,  2., nan,  4., nan,  6., nan,  8., nan])
In [269]: def interpolate_values(A):
     ...:     ''' fills values between pairs of events'''
     ...:     if type(A) ==list :
     ...:         A= np.array(A)
     ...:     ok = ~pd.isna(A)
     ...:     xp = ok.nonzero()[0]
     ...:     fp = A[~pd.isna(A)]
     ...:     x  = pd.isna(A).nonzero()[0]
     ...:     A[pd.isna(A)] = np.interp(x, xp, fp)
     ...:     A = [round(i) for i in A]
     ...:     return A
     ...: 
In [270]: interpolate_values(A)
Out[270]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
```

But if I change `A` to `object` dtype (a likely case if derived from a dataframe):

```
In [271]: interpolate_values(A.astype(object))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-271-0ca27d4b7eab>", line 1, in <module>
    interpolate_values(A.astype(object))
  File "<ipython-input-269-b3e686c021f8>", line 9, in interpolate_values
    A[pd.isna(A)] = np.interp(x, xp, fp)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in interp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1428, in interp
    return interp_func(x, xp, fp, left, right)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Actually casting code is inside the `interp_func`, but that apparently is compiled code, and thus does not give us further details of what it was trying to cast.

We can get more information by adding a print line:

```
In [275]: def interpolate_values(A):
     ...:     ''' fills values between pairs of events'''
     ...:     if type(A) ==list :
     ...:         A= np.array(A)
     ...:     ok = ~pd.isna(A)
     ...:     xp = ok.nonzero()[0]
     ...:     fp = A[~pd.isna(A)]
     ...:     x  = pd.isna(A).nonzero()[0]
     ...:     print(repr(x), repr(xp), repr(fp))    # NEW LINE
     ...:     A[pd.isna(A)] = np.interp(x, xp, fp)
     ...:     A = [round(i) for i in A]
     ...:     return A
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [276]: interpolate_values(A)
array([], dtype=int64) array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 8.])
Out[276]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]

In [277]: interpolate_values(A.astype(object))
array([], dtype=int64) array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 8.0], dtype=object)
....
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

`x` and `xp` are the same, but `fp` has changed to `object` dtype.  It can't perform numeric interpolation on `object` values; they need to be `float`.